# Return the first two string with a matching keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I get returned and aggregated list that is a string. I only want to display two items and remove the rest. Looking to do this in javascript.

I have something that looks like this:

```
"type:of:pets:pet:304126008:pet:328464062:pet:329003654:pet:274825265:pet:302508993"
```

I want to return the first two pets and strip off the rest:

```
"type:of:pets:pet:304126008:pet:328464062"
```

I tried to do something like:

```
var types = "type:of:pets:pet:304126008:pet:328464062:pet:329003654:pet:274825265:pet:302508993"

types.split('type:of:pets:pet', 2);
```

Looks like it doesnt take account of the numbers that I need as well.

Comment: What did you try? Do you have any code to show? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can slice 7 words, so that you keep 3 first words and 2 following pairs.

```js
const types = "type:of:pets:pet:304126008:pet:328464062:pet:329003654:pet:274825265:pet:302508993";

const r = types.split(':').slice(0, 7).join(':');

console.log(r)
```

Swap `const` to `var` if needed for es5 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = 'type:of:pets:pet:304126008:pet:328464062:pet:329003654:pet:274825265:pet:302508993';

const start = 'type:of:pets';
const petDelimiter = ':pet:';
const pets = input.substr(start.length + petDelimiter.length).split(petDelimiter);
const result = start + pets.slice(0, 2).map(pet => petDelimiter + pet).join('');

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex:

```js
    var pets = "type:of:pets:pet:304126008:pet:328464062:pet:329003654:pet:274825265:pet:302508993".match(/(pet:[0-9]+)/g);
    console.log("type:of:pets:" + pets.slice(0, 2).join(":"));
```